# Canvas изменение размера холста

Tags: java, android, canvas, width, viewport

Как изменить размер холста в canvas (java android)?

Comment: не проще размер view изменить?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, null, new RectF(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight), null);
```

Отрисовка прямоугольника от левого-верхнего угла, где:
canvasWidth, canvasHeight - длина и ширина соответственно